# How can I make parts of a reusable component's template optional in a Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with **Vue 3**, **TypeScript** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I have a **movie card** component (`MovieCard.vue`) that I use in (at least) 2 diffrent contexts and I want it to behave slightly difrentlly from one context to another.

```
<template>
  <div class="movie card" @click="showDetails(movie.id)">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img
        :src="movieCardImage"
        :alt="movie.title"
        class="img-fluid"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{ movie.title }}</h2>
      <p class="card-desc">{{ movie.overview }}</p>
      <span :title="`Score: ${movie.vote_average}`" class="score">{{ movie.vote_average}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
      <p class="m-0 release">
        Release date: {{ dateTime(movie.release_date) }}
      </p>
      <p v-if="movieGenres" class="m-0 pt-1">
        <span class="genre" v-for="genre in movieGenres" :key="genre.id">
          {{ genre.name }}
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import moment from "moment";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieCard",

  props: {
    movie: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    genres: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    genericCardImage: require("../assets/generic-card-image.png"),
  }),

  methods: {
    dateTime(value: any) {
      return moment(value).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    },

    showDetails(movie_id: any) {
      let movie_url = `movie/${movie_id}`;
      window.open(movie_url, "_self");
    },
  },

  computed: {
    movieCardImage() {
      return !this.movie?.backdrop_path
        ? this.genericCardImage
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`;
    },

    movieGenres() {
      if (this.genres) {
        let genres = this.genres;
        return this.movie?.genre_ids
          .filter((genre_id: number) => genre_id in genres)
          .map((genre_id: number) => genres[genre_id])
          .filter((genre: { name: string }) => genre.name.length > 0);
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The first context is the **MoviesList.vue** component

```
<template>
  <div class="row list">
    <div
      v-for="movie in movies"
      :key="movie.id"
      class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"
    >
      <MovieCard :movie="movie" :genres="genres" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../env";
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MoviesList",
  components: { MovieCard },

  props: {
    listType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    searchTerm: "",
    movies: [],
    genres: [],
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.listMovies();
    this.getGenres();
  },

  methods: {
    listMovies() {
      axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.$props.listType}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movies = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    getGenres() {
      axios
        .get(`${env.api_url}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${env.api_key}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.genres = response.data.genres;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The result:

[image]

The second context is the **ActorDetails.vue** component, where I want it displayed without the votes average "bubble":

```
<div v-if="knownFor" class="movies">
    <h2 class="section-title">Known For</h2>
    <div class="row list">
        <div
            v-for="item in knownFor"
            :key="item.id"
            class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"
        >
            <MovieCard :movie="item" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *desired* result:

[image]

#### Stackblitz

You can see a Stackblitz **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-68kyvk)**.

#### The goal

I want to make this part of the movie card component *optional*:

```
<span :title="`Score: ${movie.vote_average}`" class="score">{{ movie.vote_average}}</span>
```

I have tried the "obvious" way, in the **ActorDetails** component, but it does not work (due to scoped styles, which I prefer to keep):

```
.score {
    display: none !important;
}
```

##### What is an easy and reliable way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another prop to the movieCard component as a Boolean and pass it as true/false depending if you want the card to have a rating or not.

```
<span v-if="showRating" :title="`Score: ${movie.vote_average}`" class="score d-flex">{{movie.vote_average}}</span>
```

and on props

```
showRating: {
   type: Boolean,
   default: false,
},
```

and then on MoviesList component:

```
<MovieCard :showRating="true" :movie="movie" :genres="genres" />
```

Comment: `:showRating="true"` can be reduced to `showRating` for a bool prop, but otherwise it is as simple as that.